# KeyListeners not responding when added to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, key-bindings

I've been reading the java documentation and am trying to understand key listeners and their uses. I managed to make a simple program where 'w' and 's' toggled the background colour, however when I tried to make them move a painted ball they stopped responding. I am fairly sure it isn't a painting issue as I read through the JavaDocs common painting issues. I've set the JFrame as focuseable (or at least I think I have). If anyone could point me In the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the main class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class frame {

    public static void main(String[] args){

         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
         {                 
            @Override
             public void run()
             {       
                 showGui();                                                   
             }
         });        
    }

    public static void showGui(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Testing..");
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
          f.setFocusable(true);
            f.add(new Gui());
            f.setSize(300,300);
            f.setVisible(true);              
    }
}
```

and the Gui/KeyListener class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Gui extends JPanel {

    public Gui(){
        HandlerClass handle = new HandlerClass();
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
         addKeyListener(handle);
    }

    int x = 30;
    int y = 30;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);   


    }

    private class HandlerClass implements KeyListener{

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyChar()){
            case 'w': 
            repaint(x,y+1, 20,20);
                break;
            case 's': 
                repaint(x,y-1, 20,20);
                System.out.println("testing if this fires");
            break;
            }               
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            //todo
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            //todo

        }

    }

}
```

Any pointings in the right direction would be very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyListener` will only respond to key events when the component it is attached to is focusable and has focus.

`JPanel` by default does not meet either of these requirements (by default, it is not focusable).

For these reasons, it is not recommended that you use `KeyListener`, but instead use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which has the ability to overcome these issues

Comment: double jinks and a 1+ punch back!

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I wasn't sure if it was a glaring oversight on my part or if I needed to totally change the way I was going about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you've searched this site at all, you'll know this solution already: don't use KeyListeners but rather Key Bindings. If you haven't searched this site, well you should have done this before asking the question.

e.g.: [a previous answer of mine with example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10359712/522444)

Comment: SO I bit the bullet and learned how to use them and I just now got it working. Thank you for the insight on using them over KeyListeners!

Answer (score 0):

```
repaint(x,y+1, 20,20);
```

You are painting `y` slightly higher, however you are not actually changing `y`.  Try:

```
repaint(x,++y, 20,20);
```

The same applies (in the other direction) for your other listener.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, it wasn't the issue I was looking to fix but it was an issue, much appreciated!